# adobe air ipad first load up screen AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Quick question: why adobe air load up with a black screen in iPad(inital load screen when the app first launch)? Is there a way you can get around it byload up with the a bitmap or movieClip existed on the stage?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without Flex**

Yes, this is possible on iOS without the use of Flex. This process involves placing a Default image in your project root.

More info can be found here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000

On Android I do not think there is a similar bit of functionality. I believe this tries to come close:

http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=817

**With Flex**

When using the Flex SDK you have the ability to set a splash screen inside if your Application:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
splashScreenImage="@Embed('spash.png')"
splashScreenScaleMode="letterbox">
```

As of Flex 4.6 you also have the ability to set an array of splash screen images for use on different size screens.

This is done by defining a SpashScreenImage.mxml file:

```
 <s:SplashScreenImage xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<s:SplashScreenImageSource dpi="160--" aspectRatio="portrait" source="@Embed('portrait.png')"/>
<s:SplashScreenImageSource dpi="160--" aspectRatio="landscape" source="@Embed('landscape.png')"/>

</s:SplashScreenImage>
```

And back in your app:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
splashScreenImage="SpashScreenImage">
```

More info here:

http://devgirl.org/2012/01/20/flex-mobile-development-dynamic-splash-screens/

Comment: Sorry :) I mean can I use as3 to achieve that?

Comment: on iOS you don't need AS3 to add a startup image. It's really just adding a Default.png to your project root. Check the first link I posted

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something misleading here.

On iOS, you need to set the splashScreenImage AND include the "Default.png"

When the app starts, you will immediately see the "Default.png" image being scaled up. Almost immediately after that you will the "SplashScreenImage" show.

The Default image is showing before the app begins to load... the SplashScreenImage shows as the app loads.